# How to find out available listbox item functions from MSDN?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I write a C++/CLI program using a listbox. I google for half an hour to find a way to clear all the exist items in the listbox. I finally see a "Clear()" function from a C# forum. I test the function in my program and it worked.

I have visited msdn website. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items.aspx

I could not find any "clear" method in that page. I am lucky this time to use a C# forum hint to solve my C++ problem, but I want to know the right way to find the information that I need from MSDN.

THanks

Answer (score 0):

It was there you just did not drill down deep enough. The `Items` property is a [`ListBox::OjectCollection Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.aspx). The collection class has the [`Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.clear.aspx) Function. You can find out most of the information you need by searching the MSDN site and exploring all of the links on the page that pertain to the function you are looking for.

Comment: You are right. I should go ListBox::ObjectCollection  to have a deeper investigation.